# MS Access ODBC 64 drivers

Tags: windows-10, drivers, odbc

I had to reinstall Windows 10 Pro and this went well. When I started using my program, there were some driver related problems with respect to my application connecting to an MS Access database. I am using MS Access runtime 16 and I installed it to have access to ODB6 64 bit drivers, which were not showing in the ODBC dialog. It seemed that temporarily I could use an existing ile dsn, but no system or user dsn.

I attach one image, which currently is the similar for all three type of DSNs. Only only drivers for mdb files are listed, no 64 bit accdb drivers.

[user DSN lists driver for accdb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HGsa.png) , but this is no DSN.

Attached is the dsn file my program is using: When I am selecting the respective user DSN for configuration, the following error message is popping up: Error Message when attempting to configure an existing, previously working DSN

[ODBC Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haQbR.png)

[ODBC]
DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)
UID=admin
UserCommitSync=Yes
Threads=3
SafeTransactions=0
PageTimeout=5
MaxScanRows=8
MaxBufferSize=2048
FIL=MS Access
DriverId=25
DefaultDir=C:\ExampleDir
DBQ=C:\ExampleDir\app\pp.accdb
Any idea how to tackle this problem?
I added the image for the properties of the odbc admin tool, which I called from the control panel to verify that I am calling the correct odbc admin tool:
[image: Properties of the ODBC admin tool]

As to suggestion of John and Ramhound I uninstalled everything looking like MS Office and re-installed the 64-bit version of Microsoft 365. As this failed expected results, Ramhound requested a repair of my Windows 10 Pro installation. I did this and all was okay. I attach another image to show that all drivers are available for my convenience:[image: ODBC64 drivers show correctly during Dsn creation]

Comment: Did you happen to install Office 32-bit?  That might cause your problem, otherwise, I am not certain.

Comment: Your screenshot clearly shows the ODBC data administrator is a 32-bit application. Which means you have mistakenly installed a 32-bit version of Office. Install a 64-bit version of Office

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you reinstalled Windows, you apparently installed the 32-bit version of Office.   That is easy to do.

Uninstall Office.  Usually there is just one entry in Programs and Features, but check if any others.

You must completely uninstall the 32-bit app before the 64-bit version can be installed.

Restart.

Now install the 64-bit version of Office.  ODBC should work after that.

If all this does not work, do a Windows 10 Repair Install

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

Comment: @Michaelinscarbororough - [Edit] your question and update your question

Comment: Yes, it worked. I can see my 64 bit drivers, the .accdb extension, my program is working again, Thank you a thousand times. I was afraid, I never would be able to ... Thank you. :)

Comment: You may wish to accept my answer in this case